# asynchronous form submit in asp.net MVC 3

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I am working on asp.net 3 application. I have a view which is report of data coming from different tables. on this view, I need to create a form with input elements. This form should be submitted without postback.

1) Should I create a partial view or add it inside current view / In later case Do I need to create/update viewmodel that is passed to view?

2) How can I post the form asynchronously using partial view or inside same view ?

Regards,
Asif Hameed

Comment: @Darin and should I create partial view ? any example of using ajax in this case ?

Comment: yes you could create a partial view that will hold the part of the view that needs to be updated (if any).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create the partial view for this form, and instead of posting back, use jQuery to handle the click event, which will fire a jQuery.post() to your Action that processes the data.  Your action should then return the (updated) partial view, with which you can use

```
$('div.yourcontainerclass').html(data)
```

in your success event handler of the jQuery post to reload the updated partial view.

Comment: Do I need to use Ajax or Ajax with JQuery ?

Comment: I use jQuery for my Ajax because it's all encapsulated in easy-to use cross-browser-friendly function calls.

Comment: @Keith, how do you post the form using jQuery's post method? I get how to handle the click event, I know how to use post, but I don't see how you would get the input values from the form and include them in the post?

Answer (score 0):

Use `Ajax.BeginForm` to let MVC handle it asynchronously. There are overloads for you to set what happens after the response is returned. Whether you use a partial view or not should probably depend on if you're planning to reuse it, or if it fits within your model.